# TDS on build server; license exception

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tds

I'm trying to build a TDS project the TFS hosted server. The project uses the HedgehogDevelopment.TDS package, but when build time comes, a license exception occurs.

I am passing the owner and key information to visual studio in this way:
 `/p:TDS_Owner="$(TDSOwner)" /p:TDS_Key="$(TDSKey)"`
Where the variables are the owner and key. I have verified that the values are correct, yet I still get a license exception, indicating that TDS cannot find these values.

Is there a flaw in how I am giving visual studio these parameters? How can I get a TDS project to build using the HedgehogDevelopment.TDS package?

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you have installed TDS on the build server.

You can actually **include the License info with a config file** by following below steps.

1. Add this file manually here: `xxx(TDSFilesFolder)\HedgehogDevelopment\xxxProject\vx.0`
2. Call the file **TDSLicense.config**
3. Save the following (with your license information in) in the file:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <license Owner="CompanyName" Key="aaaa-bbb-ccc-dddd" />`

If it's a permissions issue with reading the license from the registry - this should sort it out. More detail info you can take a look a this [blog](http://www.glass.lu/Blog/Archive/Working%20with%20TDS%20and%20TFS%20in%20the%20cloud).

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the answer. The issue I'm having however, is that I can't install TDS on the build server. In theory, it's possible to build a TDS project without TDS installed, as long as you have the "HedgehogDevelopment.TDS" package installed in the project. But as per the original question, it's giving me a license exception.

Comment: Did your local environment also without  TDS installed only with the package? Did this error only occurs through TFS build not with your local dev? You must make sure the environment on your build sever(build agent) are as same as your local.This will greatly reduce the risk of build failures.